# Solve the initial value problem, $y'-xe^y=2e^y$, $y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By using an integrating factor, I get a general solution of $$y=\ln\left(\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{x^2}{2}+2x-c}\right)$$

Applying the initial condition I find $c=-1$ but I'm not sure if this is correct.

To verify the exact solution would I be correct in substituting $y'$ and $y$ into the IVP to show

$$\dfrac{-2}{\dfrac{x^2}{2}+2x+c}=\dfrac{-2}{\dfrac{x^2}{2}+2x+c}?$$

Comment: Yes. Formally you also have to check that $y(0)=0$.

Comment: @user51462: Is your solution correct? $y(x) = -\ln(-x^2/2-2 x+1)$

Comment: @Amzoti Sorry, I've revised the question to read $y(x) = -\ln(x^2/2+2x-1)$, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the obvious way is to plug in and check that both sodes of the ODE agree and that initial condition is satisfied.

Another way for a quick sanity check, let $z = e^{-y}$ and then
$$\begin{split}
z' &= -e^{-y}y' = -x-2, \quad \text{so}\\
z  &= -x^2/2-2x-C \quad \text{and}\\
y  &= -\ln(z) = \ln(1/z) = \ln \left( \frac{-1}{x^2/2+2x+C} \right).
\end{split}
$$

Yet another way is to note that $y' = e^y(x+2)$, or equivalently, $e^{-y}y' = x+2$, which is separable and integrates to $-e^{-y} = x^2/2+2x+C$...